# new and initialize in smalltalk - how to pass parameters to initialize

Tags: smalltalk

In smalltalk, when we create a object by calling new which calls initialize . I want to initialize but with my own parameters(passed at run time). How can I do that.

e.g. `Myobjcet new`

but how do I pass parameters to this so they get passed to initialize.
I am using Pharo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I recall, reimplementing class methods `new` and `initialize` should be avoided.

Instead, you can create your own class method (other than new or initialize) that takes parameters, and use those when creating your new instance. For example in `Squeak` look at the class method `with:` for class `Collection`. It first creates a collection instance, and then adds to the instance the object passed as an argument.

```
with: anObject 
    "Answer an instance of me containing anObject."

    ^ self new
        add: anObject;
        yourself
```

Your `Pharo` maybe based on Squeak, so you should find the same, or a similar class method for `Collection` in your image.

Comment: So is this a nice way to make instantiate object by calling a class method. I dont know. would like to know if its a good practice.

Comment: If you need to initialize newly created objects at the time of their creation, then yes, creating your own class methods is (I believe) good practice. There are more experienced Smalltalkers here, so they'll chime in eventually on this matter. If they say otherwise, then I'd trust their opinion over mine. :)

Answer (score 5):

Correctly writing the instantiation and initialization code of complex object hierarchies is tricky in Smalltalk. What is more, the default initialization logic as implemented in `Object` is different across different Smalltalk dialects (i.e. Pharo decided to introduce a default initializer, making things worse).

To avoid confusion and to have clear and consistent rules the Seaside team decided to apply the following rules for all their code:

[Object-Initialization at Seaside](https://github.com/SeasideSt/Seaside/wiki/Object-Initialization)

Also the Seaside code includes Code Critic rules that check for mistakes in the use of the proposed initialization pattern.

Comment: In reading that over, I think that was more or less the rules I had come up with for myself over the years, largely through trial and error (aka shooting my foot off). I've booked marked that for future reference.